# Iterate over the sorted elements in a collection in tuples

Tags: collections, rust, iteration

I am trying to iterate over the sorted elements in a collection in tuples of 2 or more.

If I had a `Vec`, I could call

```
for window in my_vec.windows(2) {
    // do something with window
}
```

but `Vec`s aren't implicitly sorted, which would be really nice to have. I tried to use a `BTreeSet` instead of a `Vec`, but I don't seem to be able to call `windows` on it.

When trying to call

```
for window in tree_set.iter().windows(2) {
    // do something with window
}
```

I get the error

```
no method named `windows` found for type `std::collections::btree_set::Iter<'_, Card>` in the current scope
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Itertools provides the [`tuple_windows`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.5.8/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuple_windows) method:

```
extern crate itertools;

use itertools::Itertools;
use std::collections::BTreeSet;

fn main() {
    let items: BTreeSet<_> = vec![1, 3, 2].into_iter().collect();

    for (a, b) in items.iter().tuple_windows() {
        println!("{} < {}", a, b);
    }
}
```

---

Note that `windows` is a method on *slices*, not on iterators, and it returns an iterator of subslices of the original slice. A `BTreeMap` presumably cannot provide that same iterator interface because it isn't built on top of a contiguous hunk of data; there's going to be some value that isn't immediately next in memory to the subsequent value.